# Split dataset into multiple by column names

Tags: r, dplyr, grepl

I am trying to split a dataset into multiple ones based on the column names:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(column_vals)){
  dataset_filtered <- dataset_metadata %>% 
  filter(characteristics..strain == column_vals[i,1], 
                          characteristics..age == column_vals[i,2])
  samples <- dataset_filtered[,1]
  samples <- substr(samples, 1, 22)
  exprs_filtered <- as.data.frame(exprs) %>% filter(colnames(exprs) %in% 
 samples)
  saveRDS(exprs_filtered, paste0(path, i, sep=""))
}
```

`samples` is a `character` array that contains different column names that need to be selected at each iteration. With above code I am getting an error:

[image]

`exprs` has dimensions `21266x24185`. I tried using `grepl` function:

```
is.in <- grepl(paste(colnames(exprs), collapse="|"), samples)
exprs_filtered <- exprs[, is.in]
```

But it is giving me another error:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? How to solve the problem? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

> Update

I tried transposing the `exprs` dataset: `as.data.frame(t(exprs)) %>% ...` and the error was gone, but the filtering was still not working: I am getting zero filtered results for each iteration. The `exprs` dataset looks the following way:

[image]

One of the `samples` character array:

[image]

Comment: Can you post a small dadaset example? Something enough to reproduce the error. Preferably using `dput(samples)` or if `samples` is too big `dput(head(samples, 20))`.

Comment: please provide an actual dataset. Otherwise, youll get downvoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is 21266x24185, the error suggests that you might need to transpose exprs or samples using `t()` to get the same orientation.

### edit:

R has appended an X to your exprs headers, so that they no longer match those in sample. When reading the exprs file (e.g. `read.csv()`) add the argument `check.names = F`, which will prevent this - though use with caution as syntactically invalid headers might affect other functions. See `?make.name` for more info

If this still doesn't fix the problem, confirm that some of the headers in expr do indeed match samples so that we expect an output.

If you provide examples that contain matching data in a format that we can copy into R (text, not images), we may be able to help further if this doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, but the filtering is still not working the way it is implemented in my code.